# Is there any flexible but simple auto-complete JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

Auto-complete seems to be a standard tool on web sites. Surprisingly, it is hard to find a ready-to-use solution in Internet. I have some basic requirements to the code:

1. I want to see only those words that start from the typed symbols (not those words that contain the types substring somewhere in the middle).
2. I want to be able to set the maximal number of words in the drop-dawn menu.
3. I want to be able to set style of the drop-dawn menu (color of the background, color of typed substring, color of rest of the word).
4. Suggested words has to be requested from the web-server (I do not want to load all possible values at once, since it is going to be a huge array of values).
5. There is just one example-file that I can just copy to my server and see that it works (then I can start to modify it to put there my content and set my style).

Do I want to much or there is something in the Internet?

**ADDED:**

As the first answer suggest, there is a [solution provided by JQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). I have managed to make it work. However it was not trivial, since the code is given out of the context. First it is not clear where I need to put this code (head?, body?). Then if I put it in the body it start to work only after I put this stuff to the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />       
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/js/demos.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/themeroller/themeswitchertool/" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It was not written on the page that I need to use this lines to make the code work. I copied this lines from the head of the page that provide the example of the auto-complete.

Moreover, I still have the problem since the auto-complete search all the words that contain the typed substring (and I need the words that start from the typed substring).

Comment: The last one isn't clear. First of all, you'll probably need at least a JavaScript file and a server-side file.  Do you mean a server-side language source file (if so, what language?) implementing an API?  If it's a static data file, that contradicts 4.  A static data file would require the JavaScript to download all of the possibilities.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen, I see the point. Let me correct myself. I want to use JavaScript, I am OK with the data for the autocomplete that is loaded together with the page (so, no Ajax) and I still would like to have one complete-html-example-page with working code (for "why" you can see my extension of the original question).

Comment: The code you just added is loading everything including the kitchen sink. All you need is jquery.min.js, jquery-ui.min.js and a one tailor made css (create one at http://jqueryui.com). All this stuff goes in the head. Other lines of code (wrapped inside `$(document).ready()`) go inside a script tag which itself can go anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this demo:

http://jsbin.com/oniji4

> Moreover, I still have the problem since the auto-complete search all the words that contain the typed substring (and I need the words that start from the typed substring).

For this you need to implement your own implementation of the source parameter. Documentation says that you can specify the following as the source:

- an Array with local data
- a String, specifying a URL
- a Callback

Now that you say that you want the suggested words to come from a server, you should use the second option (specify a URL for JSONP). That allows you to handle "I need the words that *start* from the typed substring" part.

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery is an option as library, the UI plugin offers a great autocomplete.

[jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have extended my answer to give my feedback to the solution that you have proposed.